# Get and use DbSet by type set at runtime in EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbset

I want to get a `DbSet` based on a type set at runtime so I can then use it to add, remove or update entities in the `DbContext`.

As I understand it, the way to do that in EF 6 would be, for example :

```
context.Set(entity.GetType()).Add(entity);
```

However, EF Core does not have access to the non-generic method `Set (Type entityType)` but only to the generic methods `Set<TEntity>([NotNullAttribute] string name) where TEntity : class` and `Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class`; it also does not have access to the non-generic class `DbSet` but only to the generic version `DbSet<TEntity>`, all of which makes coding an EF Core equivalent to the code above very difficult. Still, as it would be very convenient for me, I'd like to know if there exists an alternative.

Edit : Well, this is embarrassing. So apparently I am an idiot and did not realize that the class `DbContext` already had its own methods `Add`, `Update` and `Remove`. Thanks to the people who still took the time to answer me anyway.

Comment: And what would you do with such an `IQueryable` how would you query it if you don't know its type? Do you have an interface? Also if you just want to add the entity you can do `context.Add(entity)` no generics needed.

Comment: Basically `context.Add(entity)` is enough. I know what to do with these generics, but I do not understand why it is needed. Another generic repository?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv A `DecoratorServiceInjectorAdapterRepositoryUnitOfWorkFacade<T>` - they _really_ care about being able to pivot their data layer _within minutes_ of it becoming a headline on geeksforgeeksdotcom.

Comment: The question's code is a red flag in all EF versions. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work for specific domain/use cases, not a connection to be abstracted